# Linux split big files by chunks

Tags: linux

I have a big file (15GB) located in my host.

I want to split this file into chunks of 200MB.

Currently, I do it using:

```
split -a 3 -d -b 200MB my_big_file /tmp/chunk_
```

The problem is that for now I have only 10GB free space, I want to split it by offset, meaning that the first step is to read from the big file 7GB, split it using `split`, remove the split files and then split from 7GB to 15GB.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux: Using split on limited space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858459/linux-using-split-on-limited-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dd` command to read the file and specify value of block size as `1` and value of `count` as exactly half the number of bytes in file in order to read first half of file and redirect the output of `dd` command to `split` command, like this:

*(Assumptions: `big_file` is name of your `15GB` file and its size, in bytes, is exactly `15GB`)*:

```
# dd if=big_file bs=1 count=8053063680 | split -a 3 -d -b 200MB - /tmp/chunk_
```

This will split the first half of file in chunks of `200MB`.

Note that `8053063680` is half of number of bytes in `15GB` (`16106127360` bytes).

For second half

```
# dd if=big_file bs=1 skip=8053063680 count=8053063680 | split -a 3 -d -b 200MB - /tmp/chunk_
```

Again, be sure about the exact size of your file in bytes and based on that give value to `count` and `skip`.

Comment: There is a way to make it faster? to change the ```bs``` or something like that?

Comment: Yes, increasing `bs` will make things faster because `bs` specify the bytes that it read/write at a time but remember, you have to respectively change the `count` as well. For e.g. if `bs=1024` then `count` should be `count=7864320` for reading `8053063680` bytes.